# ImportError: No module named MapReduce in Cloud9

Tags: python, mapreduce, importerror, cloud9-ide

I'm using Cloud9 (https://c9.io) and 'm trying to import MapReduce and I'm receiving "`ImportError: No module named MapReduce`". Someone can help-me to install this library in Cloud9 python environment?

```
#--------------------------------------------------------------------
import MapReduce
import sys

mr = MapReduce.MapReduce()
.
.
.
```

Comment: In your python console can you do `import MapReduce` without any errors ?

Comment: Is that your custom app? If not you have to do a pip install

Comment: I receiving: "import MapReduce ImportError: No module named MapReduce". If I use "import mapreduce" with (M&R) in small cap I receive this message: "mr =  mapreduce.mapreduce()
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable"

Comment: I installed "easy_install mrs-mapreduce"

Comment: Are you using the MapReduce from the datasci class? If yes, this is not an official library. You will find the MapReduce simulator at:  https://github.com/uwescience/datasci_course_materials/tree/master/assignment3

Comment: Exactily, ´m using the MapReduce from the datasci class. I will try run this lib, tnks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

download MapReduce.py file from

https://github.com/uwescience/datasci_course_materials/blob/master/assignment3/MapReduce.py

and import in main python module

```
import imp
MapReduce = imp.load_source('MapReduce', 'C:/../YourDirectory/MapReduce.py')
```